# Angular Module does not have 'ngModuelDef' property

Tags: angular, compilation, ng-modules

Currently I am facing a strange Angular error. After a few minutes I am getting the following Error Message in my Browser Log:

Type MyContainerModule does not have 'ngModuleDef' property. The project gets reloaded all the time. Sometimes I get also the message "Type BrowserModule does not have 'ngModuleDef' property."

I am using Angular 8.

If I delete my Node_modules folder and reinstall with npm i, the problem disappears for a few minutes.

Comment: i deleted some of my Vs Code Extensions and it seems the Message is gone

Comment: Can you share with us which one making this problem?